# Error while building binaries for freeglut in Eclipse C++ (using MinGW): "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector"

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cmake, mingw

I'm attempting to create binaries for the freeglut library (version 3.2.2). The IDE I'm using is Eclipse for C/C++ version 2022-03 (4.23.0), and using MinGW (not MinGW-w64), on Windows 10.

I'm a bit new to this but here's what I've done so far:

- Downloaded the source code for freeglut 3.2.2 (from http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/)
- Used CMake (3.23.2) to configure the source code for "Eclipse CDT 4 - MinGW Makefiles", and generated the makefiles (didn't change any default values while doing so)
- I assume the next step is to import the generated project into Eclipse and build it (any tutorial I could find uses Visual Studio, so I'm not certain), but once I do start building the project, I get some errors. Build log below (excuse my directory naming):

```
17:34:23 **** Build of project freeglut@freeglut-3.2.2-build2 ****
"C:\\MinGW\\bin\\mingw32-make.exe" all 
D:\dick\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -SD:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2 -BD:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2-build2 --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
D:\dick\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_progress_start D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2-build2\CMakeFiles D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2-build2\\CMakeFiles\progress.marks
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make  -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory 'D:/dick/libraries/freeglut-3.2.2-build2'
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make  -f CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/depend
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'D:/dick/libraries/freeglut-3.2.2-build2'
D:\dick\CMake\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2 D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2 D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2-build2 D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2-build2 D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2-build2\CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\DependInfo.cmake --color=
Scanning dependencies of target freeglut
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'D:/dick/libraries/freeglut-3.2.2-build2'
C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make  -f CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/build
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory 'D:/dick/libraries/freeglut-3.2.2-build2'
[  1%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_callbacks.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_callbacks.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_callbacks.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_callbacks.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_callbacks.c
[  2%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_cursor.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_cursor.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_cursor.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_cursor.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_cursor.c
[  2%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_display.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_display.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_display.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_display.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_display.c
[  3%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_ext.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_ext.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_ext.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_ext.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_ext.c
[  4%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_font_data.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_font_data.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_font_data.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_font_data.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_font_data.c
D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_font_data.c:1902:22: warning: 'TimesRoman24_Character_159' defined but not used [-Wunused-const-variable=]
 1902 | static const GLubyte TimesRoman24_Character_159[] = { 26,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 85, 85, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 64,  0, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 64,  0, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 64,  0, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 64,  0, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 64,  0, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 64,  0, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 64,  0, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 85, 85, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0};
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_font_data.c:1901:22: warning: 'TimesRoman24_Character_158' defined but not used [-Wunused-const-variable=]
 1901 | static const GLubyte TimesRoman24_Character_158[] = { 26,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 85, 85, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 64,  0, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 64,  0, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 64,  0, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 64,  0, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 64,  0, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 64,  0, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 64,  0, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 85, 85, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0};
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_font_data.c:1900:22: warning: 'TimesRoman24_Character_157' defined but not used [-Wunused-const-variable=]
 1900 | static const GLubyte TimesRoman24_Character_157[] = { 26,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 85, 85, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 64,  0, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 64,  0, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 64,  0, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 64,  0, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 64,  0, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 64,  0, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 64,  0, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 85, 85, 64,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0};
      |                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    (several hundred other warnings like the ones above that I've ommitted)

[  5%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_gamemode.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_gamemode.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_gamemode.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_gamemode.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_gamemode.c
[  6%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_geometry.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_geometry.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_geometry.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_geometry.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_geometry.c
[  6%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_gl2.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_gl2.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_gl2.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_gl2.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_gl2.c
[  7%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_init.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_init.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_init.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_init.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_init.c
[  8%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_input_devices.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_input_devices.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_input_devices.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_input_devices.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_input_devices.c
[  9%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_joystick.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_joystick.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_joystick.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_joystick.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_joystick.c
[  9%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_main.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_main.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_main.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_main.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_main.c
[ 10%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_misc.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_misc.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_misc.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_misc.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_misc.c
[ 11%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_overlay.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_overlay.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_overlay.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_overlay.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_overlay.c
[ 12%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_spaceball.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_spaceball.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_spaceball.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_spaceball.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_spaceball.c
[ 12%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_state.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_state.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_state.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_state.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_state.c
[ 13%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_stroke_mono_roman.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_stroke_mono_roman.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_stroke_mono_roman.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_stroke_mono_roman.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_stroke_mono_roman.c
[ 14%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_stroke_roman.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_stroke_roman.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_stroke_roman.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_stroke_roman.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_stroke_roman.c
[ 15%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_structure.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_structure.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_structure.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_structure.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_structure.c
[ 15%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_teapot.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_teapot.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_teapot.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_teapot.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_teapot.c
[ 16%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_videoresize.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_videoresize.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_videoresize.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_videoresize.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_videoresize.c
[ 17%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_window.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_window.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_window.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_window.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_window.c
[ 18%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_font.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_font.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_font.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_font.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_font.c
[ 18%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_menu.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/fg_menu.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_menu.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\fg_menu.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\fg_menu.c
[ 19%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/mswin/fg_cursor_mswin.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/mswin/fg_cursor_mswin.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\mswin\fg_cursor_mswin.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\mswin\fg_cursor_mswin.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\mswin\fg_cursor_mswin.c
[ 20%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/mswin/fg_display_mswin.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/mswin/fg_display_mswin.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\mswin\fg_display_mswin.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\mswin\fg_display_mswin.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\mswin\fg_display_mswin.c
[ 21%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/mswin/fg_ext_mswin.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/mswin/fg_ext_mswin.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\mswin\fg_ext_mswin.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\mswin\fg_ext_mswin.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\mswin\fg_ext_mswin.c
[ 21%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/mswin/fg_gamemode_mswin.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/mswin/fg_gamemode_mswin.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\mswin\fg_gamemode_mswin.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\mswin\fg_gamemode_mswin.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\mswin\fg_gamemode_mswin.c
[ 22%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/mswin/fg_init_mswin.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/mswin/fg_init_mswin.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\mswin\fg_init_mswin.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\mswin\fg_init_mswin.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\mswin\fg_init_mswin.c
[ 23%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/mswin/fg_input_devices_mswin.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/mswin/fg_input_devices_mswin.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\mswin\fg_input_devices_mswin.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\mswin\fg_input_devices_mswin.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\mswin\fg_input_devices_mswin.c
[ 24%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/mswin/fg_joystick_mswin.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/mswin/fg_joystick_mswin.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\mswin\fg_joystick_mswin.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\mswin\fg_joystick_mswin.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\mswin\fg_joystick_mswin.c
[ 24%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/mswin/fg_main_mswin.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/mswin/fg_main_mswin.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\mswin\fg_main_mswin.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\mswin\fg_main_mswin.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\mswin\fg_main_mswin.c
D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\mswin\fg_main_mswin.c: In function 'fghWindowProcKeyPress':
D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\mswin\fg_main_mswin.c:719:7: warning: suggest explicit braces to avoid ambiguous 'else' [-Wdangling-else]
  719 |     if( keypress != -1 )
      |       ^
[ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/mswin/fg_menu_mswin.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/mswin/fg_menu_mswin.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\mswin\fg_menu_mswin.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\mswin\fg_menu_mswin.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\mswin\fg_menu_mswin.c
D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\mswin\fg_menu_mswin.c:97:2: warning: ISO C does not allow extra ';' outside of a function [-Wpedantic]
   97 | };
      |  ^
[ 26%] Building C object CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/mswin/fg_spaceball_mswin.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DFREEGLUT_EXPORTS -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DWINVER=0x0601 -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 -Dfreeglut_EXPORTS @CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/includes_C.rsp -Wall -pedantic -MD -MT CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/mswin/fg_spaceball_mswin.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\mswin\fg_spaceball_mswin.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\src\mswin\fg_spaceball_mswin.c.obj -c D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\mswin\fg_spaceball_mswin.c
D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\mswin\fg_spaceball_mswin.c: In function 'fgSpaceballHandleWinEvent':
D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\mswin\fg_spaceball_mswin.c:155:45: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
  155 |             if (pRawInput->data.hid.bRawData[0] ==
      |                                             ^
D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\mswin\fg_spaceball_mswin.c:158:71: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
  158 |                 short* pnData = (short*)(&pRawInput->data.hid.bRawData[1]);
      |                                                                       ^
D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\mswin\fg_spaceball_mswin.c:164:50: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
  164 |             else if (pRawInput->data.hid.bRawData[0] ==
      |                                                  ^
D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\mswin\fg_spaceball_mswin.c:167:71: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
  167 |                 short* pnData = (short*)(&pRawInput->data.hid.bRawData[1]);
      |                                                                       ^
D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\mswin\fg_spaceball_mswin.c:173:50: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
  173 |             else if (pRawInput->data.hid.bRawData[0] ==
      |                                                  ^
D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\mswin\fg_spaceball_mswin.c:176:91: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
  176 |                 unsigned long dwKeystate = *(unsigned long*)(&pRawInput->data.hid.bRawData[1]);
      |                                                                                           ^
D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\mswin\fg_spaceball_mswin.c:177:30: warning: unused variable 'state' [-Wunused-variable]
  177 |                 unsigned int state = GLUT_UP;
      |                              ^~~~~
D:\dick\libraries\freeglut-3.2.2\src\mswin\fg_spaceball_mswin.c:109:10: warning: unused variable 'inputCode' [-Wunused-variable]
  109 |     UINT inputCode = (UINT)wParam;
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
CMakeFiles\freeglut.dir\build.make:570: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/mswin/fg_spaceball_mswin.c.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/src/mswin/fg_spaceball_mswin.c.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'D:/dick/libraries/freeglut-3.2.2-build2'
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:131: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'D:/dick/libraries/freeglut-3.2.2-build2'
Makefile:134: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/freeglut.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
"C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

17:34:36 Build Failed. 12 errors, 395 warnings. (took 13s.501ms)
```

I can gather that the errors "subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector" actually mean, I'm just not sure why they're happening or how to avoid them, cause I can't really change the code they're from. I've tried my hardest to google this issue, but to no effect; if anyone can help me figure out what the problem here is and how to fix it, I'd be grateful.

Comment: You're not the first to have this problem, suggested solution [here](https://github.com/FreeGLUTProject/freeglut/issues/93) (no idea if it works or not).

Comment: Don't use MinGW it's very old. I have no issues building freeglut 3.2.2 with MinGW-w64 with CMake under MSYS2.